# The convergence of a sequence with infinite products

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence

I have a problem to determine convergence (sum over n). $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac {a\left( a+1^{p}\right) \ldots \left( a+n^{p}\right) }{b\left( b+1^{p}\right) \ldots \left( b+n^{p}\right) }$$where $a<b, a>0,b>0$.

I have concluded convergence for $p\leq0$ by comparing it to a constructed geometric sequence, as well as for $p=1$, using comparison test with $n^{a-b}$. But I can not use similar methods for $p>1$ and $0<p<1$.

I have some thoughts for the two parts:

When $p>1$, it seems that the limit of each term is not $0$. If the limit could be evaluated, then the divergence can be proved. My method for $p=1$ is to use the Euler Product of the gamma function, but the $p$ power makes it impossible to use this method. I am wondering if there is any kind of generalization of gamma function that is of this form.

when $0<p<1$, I compared it to the case of $p=1$, that could at least tell it converges in the range when $p=1$ converge. But it is inconclusive for the parts remaining.

Any help or hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the summation over $n$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yes

Comment: Let 
$a_n(a,p)=a\left( a+1^{p}\right) \ldots \left( a+n^{p}\right) 
$
we have:
$\ln(a_n(a,p))=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\ln(a+i^p)$ and this can be compared to:
$$\int_{0}^{n}\ln(1+x^p)dx $$

Comment: @Elaqqad Thanks, but when I tried this, it turned out to be $$\sum ^{n}_{i=1}\ln \left( a+i^{p}\right)-\sum ^{n}_{i=1}\ln \left( b+i^{p}\right)$$ for a single term, the comparison can't be used. Am I using it the wrong way?

Comment: After Mathematica gave me a nice result, I became curious as to the specific result of the limit of the terms for $p=2$ (and greater even $p$s). Since it probably is not particularly relevant to this question, I posted [a new question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1260739/evaluation-of-prod-k-1-infty-fracak2bk2)

Comment: For $p=0$ we have $S_0=\dfrac{1+a}{b-a}$ , and for $p=1$ we get $S_1=\dfrac a{b-a-1}$ .

Comment: ...which turned out not to be a super hard problem (thanks to a comment by Lucian and an answer by Jack D'Aurizio).   Well, there's the $p=2$ case solved :P.

Comment: @Lucian:  $S_1$ cannot be right for any $0<a<b$: if $b-a<1$ then your result is negative, but the series has positive terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me this is a simple application of [Raabe-Duhamel's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests#Raabe-Duhamel.27s_test). You'll get convergence for $p<1$ and, if $b-a>1$, you also get convergence for $p=1$. For $p>1$ the series diverges.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know this rule! It is really helpful to this problem.

Comment: @WilliamRiddle: The Raabe-Duhamel test is the natural thing to try when the root test (or the ratio test, which is often equivalent) fails. Convince yourself of its usefulness by studying $\sum \frac {(2n)!} {n!^2}$ first with the ratio, then with the Raabe-Duhamel test.